# Show instance for Heterogeneous List

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, heterogeneous

I am having trouble defining a Show instances for the heterogeneous list defined below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Kind

data HList xs where
     HNil :: HList TNil
     (::^) :: a -> HList as -> HList (a :^ as)

data TypeList = TNil | (:^) Type TypeList

instance Show (HList TNil) where
     show HNil = "[]"
```

I would like to give HList xs a show instance, if all types in the Typelist xs have a Show Instance. I guess one should be able to write something like

```
instance (Show a, _) => Show (HList a :^ as) where
     show (x ::^ xs) = show x ++ show xs
```

but I am unsure what to fill in the hole _.

PS: If you try this in ghci, don't forget to add the language extensions with

```
:set -XTypeInType -XTypeOperators
```

Comment: Perhaps `(Show a, Show (HList as)) => ...` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.Kind

infixr 5 ::^

data HList xs where
     HNil :: HList TNil
     (::^) :: a -> HList as -> HList (a :^ as)

data TypeList = TNil | (:^) Type TypeList

instance Show (HList TNil) where
     show HNil = "HNil"

instance (Show a, Show (HList as)) => Show (HList (a:^as)) where
     showsPrec p (x::^xs) = showParen (p>5)
       $ showsPrec 6 x . ("::^"++) . showsPrec 5 xs

main :: IO ()
main = print ((2 :: Int) ::^ "bla" ::^ HNil)
```

```
2::^"bla"::^HNil
```

Answer (score 4):

Using type families, you can express the constraint "All types have a show instance" pretty directly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeInType #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Kind

infixr 5 ::^
data HList xs where
     HNil :: HList TNil
     (::^) :: a -> HList as -> HList (a :^ as)

data TypeList = TNil | (:^) Type TypeList

type family All (c :: Type -> Constraint) (xs :: TypeList) :: Constraint where
        All c TNil = ()
        All c (x :^ xs) = (c x, All c xs)

instance All Show xs => Show (HList xs) where
    show HNil = "[]"
    show (x ::^ xs) = '[' : show x ++ go xs
      where
        go :: All Show ys => HList ys -> String
        go HNil = "]"
        go (y ::^ ys) = ',' : show y ++ go ys
```

Comment: I like this more than the other answer because `All` is reusable. Also, it avoids splitting the instance in two.

Comment: But it does use UndecidableInstances.

Comment: Yes, but it's a safe use of UndecidableInstances, since we know that `All` will terminate given a finite list.

Comment: I actually tried to construct an infinite list in TypeList. It did not work, which is surprising since the value-level analog allows this. I guess the type level language is more restrictive, so that TypeList is always a finite list.

Comment: I do love the flexibility of your All solution! It is useful for writing other instances. I am curious if there is a trick to get rid of the UndecidableInstance.

Comment: @mna, it is possible to express infinite types using type families. They're not well behaved. `type family Foo :: [Bool] where Foo = 'True ': Foo`.